# ChartJS bar chart fixed width for dynamic data sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am using ChartJs for creating bar charts. the **datasets** are dynamic.since the datasets are dynamic, the width of the bar is also changing.

For Example bar width only for one label
[image]

Bar width for many labels
[image]

**How to have fixed width for the bar irrespective of the number of labels**

i am using the following option.

```
xAxes: [{
    barPercentage: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 0.3
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the "categoryPercentage" into as many columns as possible and multiply by the number of columns in the current dataset

https://jsfiddle.net/qrwvvtxs/2/

```js
var barChartData1 = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    data: [3,2,7,4,5,7,6]
  }, {
    label: 'Dataset 2',
    backgroundColor: "#faa",
    data: [11,13,21,13,16,21,18]
  }]
};
var barChartData2 = {
  labels: ["January"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    data: [6]
  }, {
    label: 'Dataset 2',
    backgroundColor: "#faa",
    data: [11]
  }]
};

var ctx1 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
var myBar1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData1,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          barPercentage: 1,
          categoryPercentage: 0.5 / 10 * barChartData1.datasets[0].data.length
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
var myBar2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData2,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          barPercentage: 1,
          categoryPercentage: 0.5 / 10 * barChartData2.datasets[0].data.length
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow this helps a lot

Comment: @rmaksim This is a good solution. But I am facing another issue. Since we are using dynamic data, the data length should also be dynamic. For example, if data length is 24, bars will start overlap. Can you please look in to that scenario?